# SQL Query works in MySQL Workbench but not in code

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to write a transaction with two INSERT INTOs that looks like this:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO users VALUES('123', 0, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES('123', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
COMMIT;
```

This Query works fine in the MySQL Workbench but not in my Code that I wrote in JavaScript:

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    db.query(`BEGIN;
              INSERT INTO users VALUES('123', 0, 0, 0);
              INSERT INTO inventory VALUES('123', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
              COMMIT;`, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err
        res.status(200).send(result)
    })
})
```

I am getting the Error: 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

I'm using the mysql2 Package in my JavaScript Backend.

Does anybody know why this problem occurs?

EDIT: I even tried START TRANSACTION instead of BEGIN

Comment: Try using start transaction instead of begin. I'm guessing you have open transactions in sqlworkbench but statements are wrapped and auto-comitted here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that didn't work either. Same problem; It works in the workbench but not in my code.

Comment: If you split it up into 3 sperate calls does it work? Inserts return a rows affected object and it may not be able to handle that unless it's called in a sproc or split into individual statement calls